# Facilitate finding project collaborators?

Tags: feature-request

Perhaps similar to how http://careers.stackoverflow.com/ works, but more of a "Hey I have this idea X" portal where people can express an interest in using the product, working with the product, supporting it, etc...

Anything from "I want to make this 3d tetris clone with GLUT" to "Lets fork the OO.org project and do things A,B, and C with it."

There's a lot of talent in these communities, it might be a good way to gauge interest and start a dialog about your projects, find similar ones, etc...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not clear on how you're proposing to achieve what you're saying, but there is an existing Area 51 proposal called [Ideas](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/16172/ideas) that seems pretty similar to what you want. It's not too popular, though.

Comment: Are you saying that proposing it was not a good Idea? (get it?)

Comment: @Juan: what? (15)

Comment: Similar, but it would require more ranking than the reputation bar we're using right now. Gauge interest in a project, gage who wants to be involved in it, who likes it, etc...

Comment: Interesting idea, but this will probably never have enough traction to take off as a SE site of its own...